# Как вставить % в миксинах scss

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, scss

Не получается вставить % в миксины scss, могу вставит единицы em, rem, а % не знаю как.

Искал информацию, но не нашел, пробовал через #{} не получается`

```css
@mixin adp($property, $max, $min, $container: $container, $minWidth: 320) {
    $container: $container;
    $minWidth: $minWidth;

    @media (max-width: #{$container / 16 + em}) {
        #{$property}: calc(#{$min / 16 + %} + (#{$max} - (#{$min})) * ((100vw - #{$minWidth + px}) / (#{$container} - #{$minWidth})));
 }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Проблем вынести за `#{}` нет никаких. Вот так:

```
@mixin adp($property, $max, $min, $container: $container, $minWidth: 320) {
   $container: $container;
   $minWidth: $minWidth;

   @media (max-width: #{$container / 16}em) {
       #{$property}: calc(#{$min / 16}% + (#{$max} - #{$min}) * ((100vw - #{$minWidth + px}) / (#{$container}px - #{$minWidth}px)));
   }
}
```

Вы также можете использовать проценты как строку – это будет работать:

```
@mixin adp($property, $max, $min, $container: $container, $minWidth: 320) {
   $container: $container;
   $minWidth: $minWidth;

   @media (max-width: #{$container / 16 + em}) {
       #{$property}: calc(#{$min / 16 + '%'} + (#{$max} - (#{$min})) * ((100vw - #{$minWidth + px}) / (#{$container} - #{$minWidth})));
   }
}
```

---

P.S. Но учитывайте, что у Вас получается невалидное выражение с точки зрения CSS в принципе.

Comment: И ещё не понимаю, зачем вообще Вы пишете `$minWidth: $minWidth;` в теле, если эти переменные уже объявлены как параметры (глобальные переменные же сюда не подтянутся, они уже перебиты по сути)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую. На счёт minWidth тем не менее оно работает

Comment: @Vorchun Ну понятно, что оно будет работать. Но это буквально ничего не дает. Вы создаете переменную внутри с таким же именем, как и параметр, и присваиваете ей значение этого параметра, т.е создаете копию и тут же перебиваете этот параметр. Ну или другими словами делаете видимость бурной деятельности :)